# Page refreshes every 2 mins instead of 20 mins of inactivity

Tags: javascript, jquery

I used a script to check the inactivity of a user, and refresh the page if the user is inactive for 20 minutes. But, instead of that, the page refreshes every 2 minutes. Here is my code.

```
var time = new Date().getTime();
     $(document.body).bind("mousemove keypress", function(e) {
         time = new Date().getTime();
     });

     function refresh() {
         if(new Date().getTime() - time >= 60000) 
             window.location.reload(true);
         else 
             setTimeout(refresh, 15000);
     }

     setTimeout(refresh, 20000);
```

Can someone tell me what's wrong?

Comment: 60,000ms is how long?

Comment: 20 minnutes should be 1200000ms ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The values of timers in Javascript are set on ms. that is 1s = 1000 ms.

Then 20000 = 20s, 60000 = 60s,...

You function checks at first time after 20s of the page has started and then every 15s to verify if the user has more than 60s without activity. This makes the page to be reloaded after 1,20 seconds if there is no activity.

Example:

```
 var time = new Date().getTime();

 $(document.body).bind("mousemove keypress", function(e) {
     time = new Date().getTime();
 });

 function refresh() {
     if(new Date().getTime() - time >= 120000) {
         window.location.reload(true);
     } else {
         setTimeout(refresh, 5000);
     }
 }

 setTimeout(refresh, 5000);
```

This example checks the page every 5s (5000ms) to view if the user has more that 2 minutes (120000ms) without interaction

Comment: Will this slow down my page significantly?

Comment: A 5000ms timeout is not enough to slow down a browser. The instruction is really simple and uses less resources

Answer (score 2):

Simple change

```
setTimeout(refresh, 20000);
```

to

```
setTimeout(refresh, 1200000);
```

Comment: `if(new Date().getTime() - time >= 60000) ` - Shouldn't this check the current time and past time difference by 60 seconds?